# How to find a revision with particular code structure

Tags: git

When my app crashes, I get reports with call stack that look like that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.app.reader.services.receivers.MediaPlayStopReceiver.onReceive(MediaPlayStopReceiver.java:16)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2601)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

However, as I actively develop my code changes every day, so this call stack may  not reflect the current state. How can I use git to find the commit where the code looked as presented in call stack?

Comment: Have you tried [git-bisect](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search)?

Comment: *How can I use git to find the commit where the code looked as presented in call stack?* how do you intend to do that, if the call stack doesn't include the code?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, that's an interesting question)... I don't know

Comment: @zaratustra, I can't seem to figure how to use it in this case. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: git-bisect works the same in all cases. The description in the documentation should guide you through it

Comment: Do you not also get the version number of the app they're using is on? With that, you should just be able to checkout that branch/tag/commit.

Comment: @Trengot, yeah, that seems to be the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which revision of the code that is used you can use `git gui blame <path-to-MediaPlayStopReceiver>` and manually check each parent commit to find what changes has been made to line 16 and if it could cause a NPE (or use an IDE that supports history browsing for files)

If you can reproduce the problem you can run `git bisect` to find the commit that introduced the problem.